# List<Date> to Map<Date, Integer> showing amount of date elements for each minute

Tags: java, datetime, java-stream

I have a list of Java Date Objects and I would like to know how many dates are within the same minute

For example my list in epoch seconds

```
0
3
10
50
65
100
```

Should result in a map with following key value

```
new Date(0) => 4
new Date(60000) => 2
```

I am fine with using libraries for rounding java dates to minutes.

Comment: First, forget about the Date class. Use the classes from the java.time package. The javadoc is your friend.

Comment: I need to use the Date class

Comment: You probably don't. But even if what you have is a Date, start by conerting it to classes of the java.time package.

Comment: if you have list in epoch seconds, then divid all the numbers on the list by 60 and do a Math.ceil on each value on the list (Casting it to type int would work too). Then have a Map with the key as the minute and value as the frequency  Just go though the list and increment the value. Final map should have all the frequencies for each minute.

Comment: `dates.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> new Date(d.getTime() / 60000), Collectors.counting()))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

```
List<Long> epochSeconds = List.of(0L, 3L, 10L, 50L, 65L, 100L);
Map<Instant, Long> countByMinute = epochSeconds.stream()
    .map(Instant::ofEpochSecond)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(inst -> inst.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES), Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(countByMinute);
```

Output is:

> {1970-01-01T00:00:00Z=4, 1970-01-01T00:01:00Z=2}

I suggest that you don’t want to use the `Date` class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with, and I find the code clearer to read. If you need to look up in the map using a `Date` that you get from a legacy API that you cannot change right now, do the conversion in the lookup. For example:

```
System.out.println("Count for new Date(60_000) is: "
    + countByMinute.get(new Date(60_000).toInstant()));
```

> Count for new Date(60_000) is: 2

If you do insist, it is of course possible to store `Date` objects as map keys (I repeat, not recommended):

```
Map<Date, Long> countByMinute = epochSeconds.stream()
    .map(Instant::ofEpochSecond)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(inst -> Date.from(inst.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)), Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(countByMinute);
```

Output on my computer in Europe/Copenhagen time zone:

> {Thu Jan 01 01:01:00 CET 1970=2, Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970=4}

**Link:** [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with:

```
Map<Integer, Long> result = seconds.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i / 60, Collectors.counting()));
```

If you want to collect all the second values use:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> result = seconds.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i / 60));
```

If you really want to use `Date` Objects (I would not do that) you can use `new Date(i / 60 * 60_000)` instead of `i / 60`.

I would suggest using [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes instead.

Comment: I agree in the suggestion to use java.time and additionally suggest that you let that API do the time math (as in my answer). `i / 60` may seem trivial, but it takes less than you think for a reader to get in doubt about what’s seconds, what’s milliseoncds and what’s minutes. When you call a named library method, you have already made this explicit and eliminated the doubt.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but OP wants to use the old `Date` class anyway, so I just suggested to use `java.time` and didn't explain it in detail.